# How to partially mask a UITextField text in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

`--------------------`
`|` **** **** **** 1234  `|`
`--------------------`

As you can tell, I'm trying to partially mask the first 12 digits of a card number which the user types in a `UITextField`. It took me a lot of time to figure out how to separate the digits in chunks of 4. Now the challenge I'm taking up is to mask the first 12 digits with secure-entry style mask.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:
Adding code that I have tried so far:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else {
        return true
    }
    //@"●"
    let lastText = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as String
    if txtCardNumber.text?.characters.count >= 12 {
        txtCardNumber.text = "●●●● ●●●● ●●●●" // + String()
        return true
    }
    return true
}
```

Objective:  I have posted what I attempted. Not able to get past the point of using the ● 12 times after determining the length of the textField is more than 12. Stuck here. To answer your question, it needs to show the number when typed but replace with ● when the next number is type. Continue same behavior till length is 12 and then show numbers from there on till 16th digit.

Comment: Is the whole card number one string ? or is it 4 different strings composed of 4 digits?

Comment: The whole card number is one string. @Alex

Comment: So does it need to show the character when it is typed and after a delay hide it or just show an asterisk when it is typed?

Comment: Btw you should at least show what you have tried and the issues you encountered when trying to accomplish it

Comment: @LeoDabus I have posted what I attempted. Not able to get past the point of using the ● 12 times after determining the length of the textField is more than 12. Stuck here. To answer your question, it needs to show the number when typed but replace with ● when the next number is type. Continue same behavior till length is 12 and then show numbers from there on till 16th digit.

Comment: Try adding a target and a selector for editingChanged instead and do whatever you need there. `addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)`

Comment: FYI - if your `shouldChangeCharactersIn` explicitly updates the text of the text field, then you must return `false`.

Comment: @asdiu Your most recent comment needs to be put into your question. Your comment explains your goal much better than your question does.

Answer (score 1):

Updated: I'm sorry but the first version of this answer didn't work as I expected, as rmaddy pointed out. So here is my updated answer and now it works as expected.

Say you have a string with no spaces at all just yet, for example something like :

```
let yourString = "1234123412341234"
```

It is composed of 4*4 = 16 digits.

And you would like to format it like you usually see it on websites that request their users to type their credit card number, then you could do something like this to handle both the spacings **and** the symbols :

```
let yourString = "1234123412341234"
var resultString = String()

// Loop through all the characters of your string

yourString.characters.enumerated().forEach { (index, character) in

    // Add space every 4 characters

    if index % 4 == 0 && index > 0 {
        resultString += " "
    }

    if index < 12 {

        // Replace the first 12 characters by *

        resultString += "*"

    } else {

        // Add the last 4 characters to your final string

        resultString.append(character)
    }

}

print(resultString)
```

And you would get `**** **** **** 1234`

Please let me know if you have any questions !

Comment: I would love to know the reason why someone downvoted this answer though.

Comment: Try running your code in a playground. And even once you get the code to compile, it doesn't really do what is being asked. And your use of `string.index(of:)` is strange since the string can have duplicates of certain characters.

Comment: So, that's precisely why I took the time to say that I don't have a computer right now and cannot check it at the moment but that it "should" work. If I did any mistake in the code, then I'm glad you could notice it and I think you could just edit my answer instead of downvoting it, because I mean, it's not really constrctive and this is not helping in any way. :)

Comment: Posting an answer that doesn't compile and doesn't perform the desired functionality is not really constructive. Don't post code in a rush and expect others to fix your answer for you. Please take the time to post a good answer to begin with. A down vote isn't personal. It's simply a way to indicate an answer isn't helpful. Get your answer in better condition and the vote can be adjusted.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I didn't post the code in a rush but as I said I didnt have a laptop accessible so I could not check if the code would compile. The reason why I posted this answer is of course because I was expecting it to compile (but obviously I was wrong and I'm sorry for that) and thought it would help the OP. Anyway thank you for pointing this out and of course yes I will update my answer as soon as I have a laptop to check what's going on. I will be more careful in the future!