# Card Number Masking

Tags: swift, masking

I'm trying to mask card number with regex.
First 6 and last 2 chars can be shown other should "*".

```
let cardNumber: String = "5890040000000016"

print("Output: ", cardNumber.mask(regexPattern:"XXXXXXX")) // Output: 589004********16
```

How can I do that in swift?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46249283/1187415

Comment: There is no `mask` method and `"XXXXXXX"` is not a "regex pattern" so your code is meaningless. If there is something we are not seeing, show it, please.

Comment: Let me explain @matt. I want mask a card number with regex. I need a regex that can detect between first 6 and last 2 chars. I don't know if there is a regex like that. That's why it's XXXXXX. I'm just wondering.

Comment: Already, checked. @MartinR

Comment: Yes, you can make a regex that does that. But since this can be done easily without a regex, why do you "need" a regex? Is this just a matter of idle curiosity? And again I ask, what is the meaningless code for? If it has a meaning because you have a defined a `mask(regexPattern:)` method, please show that method.

Comment: No matter. Just curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question contains 2 important parts:

#### A regex that matches all characters but first 6 and last 2

```
let regexPattern = "(?<=.{6}).(?=.*.{2}$)"
```

and

#### An extension on the `String` that takes the regex and masks it:

```
extension String {

    func masked(matching regexPattern: String, with template: String = "*") throws -> String {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexPattern, options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, count)
        return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: template)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let cardNumber = "5890040000000016"
let regexPattern = "(?<=.{6}).(?=.*.{2}$)"

print("Output:", try! cardNumber.masked(matching: regexPattern))
```

> Output: 589004********16

Comment: May look nicer to use `#"..."#` rather than `"..."` because of the annoying character escaping for regex

Comment: I have got ridden of that ugly escaping at all @George. Now it is clean as heaven

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate substrings together:

```
let cardNumber = "5890040000000016"

let start = cardNumber.startIndex ..< cardNumber.index(cardNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)
let end = cardNumber.index(cardNumber.endIndex, offsetBy: -2) ..< cardNumber.endIndex
let result = cardNumber[start] + Array(repeating: "*", count: cardNumber.count - 8) + cardNumber[end]
print(result)

// Prints: 589004********16
```

Comment: where is the regex? :/

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Not a regex but it achieves the result (and will be faster too)

Comment: Good point but what about a dynamic regex?

Comment: Yeah thank you @George, that's cool it works but I'm wondering if I can do it with regex.

Comment: @KaanOzdemir You're going to need to elaborate on your requirements, because the problem you've presented makes no sense to solve with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
let s = "5890040000000016"
let patt = ##"^(\d{6})(.*)(\d{2})$"## // this is your pattern
let reg = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: patt, options: [])
if let m = reg.firstMatch(in: s, options: [], range: NSRange(s.startIndex..<s.endIndex, in: s)) {
    let r = m.range(at:2)
    let result = s.replacingCharacters(in: Range(r, in:s)!, with: String(repeating: "X", count: r.length))
    print(result) // 589004XXXXXXXX16
}
```